# In angular Typescript, when logging a structure it looks correct, but when logging a member in it, it gets undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following "prod" structure (from log):

```
cat_id: "1"
category: "2"
description: "The Nike Zoom Pegasus Turbo 2 is updated with a feather-light upper, while innovative foam brings revolutionary responsiveness to your long-distance training"
id: "2"
image: "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/43/40/8e/43408ee5a8d234752ecf80bbc3832e65.jpg"
images: "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/43/40/8e/43408ee5a8d234752ecf80bbc3832e65.jpg;https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/eQgAAOSw2XdePfc0/s-l640.jpg;https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/j~gAAOSwQ6FdG9Eh/s-l640.jpg;https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/OesAAOSwDnpeJhWN/s-l640.jpg"
price: "59.99"
quantity: "51"
short_desc: "SPORTS SHOES"
title: "Electronics"
```

but, when logging, I am getting the following results:

`console.log(prod)` -> correct, getting the above structure

`console.log(prod.images)` -> undefined

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: How are the object defined in the code?

Comment: Here is the record: [{"id":"2","title":"Electronics","image":"https://i.pinimg.com/originals/43/40/8e/43408ee5a8d234752ecf80bbc3832e65.jpg","images":"https://i.pinimg.com/originals/43/40/8e/43408ee5a8d234752ecf80bbc3832e65.jpg;https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/eQgAAOSw2XdePfc0/s-l640.jpg;","description":"The Nike Zoom Pegasus Turbo 2 is updated with a feather-light upper, while innovative foam brings revolutionary responsiveness to your long-distance training","price":"59.99","quantity":"51","short_desc":"SPORTS SHOES","cat_id":"1","category":"2"}]

Answer (score 0):

Do something instead of doing console log on prod do

`console.log(JSON.stringify(prod))`.

I am sure you won't see images property in it. Actually objects work on reference, when its printed in console directly, it keeps refering to same reference. So once you expand it it refers to same reference and shows the value. You just have to make sure that prod have images property before using the property.

Comment: It prints everything fine for the full record, but when logging the fields it is undefined. Full Record: [{"id":"2","title":"Electronics","image":"bbc3832e65.jpg","images":"c3832e65.jpg","description":"The Nike Zoom Pegasus Turbo 2 is updated with a feather-light upper, while innovative foam brings revolutionary responsiveness to your long-distance training","price":"59.99","quantity":"51","short_desc":"SPORTS SHOES","cat_id":"1","category":"2"}] , but prod.title is undefined.

Comment: did you do json.stringify as i asked?

Comment: I tried it to, unsuccessfully. Anyway I gave up and going in different direction